# swap control and capslock as default (especially for virtual display)

Tags: raspbian, vnc, keyboard

I'm new to Raspberry Pi, but not to linux - though I've never been clear on details like keyboard mapping. And I'm the type who has become addicted to swapping the capslock and control key.

I normally connect to my Raspberry Pi via VNC to a virtual display. I tried putting `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"` in `/etc/default/keyboard`, but it doesn't seem to work (even after reboot). When I enter `setxkbmap -option "ctrl:swapcaps"` in a terminal, I get an error like

```
    Couldn't interpret _XKB_RULES_NAMES property
    Use defaults: rules - 'base' model - 'pc105' layout - 'us'
    Error loading the new keyboard description
```

I'm not sure what else to try and my internet searches have turned up nothing - at least, nothing I understand. I don't get how keyboard mapping is dependent on the display, for example, but I suspect maybe it has to do with the VNC virtual display?

Any thoughts appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try and focus on the client workstation side along with the remote VNC system.

On my remote Pis and local Linux workstations I set `XKBOPTIONS=ctrl:nocaps` in the `/etc/defaults/keyboard` to replace the capslock with a control key *instead of swapping it.*

This works in a terminal using the `setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"`

On Windows workstations I install Microsoft PowerToys and do the same capslock to control change adjustment.

After that it doesn't matter where I am in the ecosystem that silly capslock behavior removed from the equation.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this! Ideally I'd still be able to use capslock somewhere though (I do use it sometimes!).